# Уменьшение нагрузки

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

У меня есть файл конфигурации, в котором есть текст, который должен выводиться на определенной странице (в файле тексты всех страниц) с файлом я соединяюсь

```
include ('/ data / config.php');
```

при этом страница размером в 2.1 KB генерируется 2 сек. Как уменьшить это время?

Comment: Код в студию

Comment: 1. Пробелы там по приколу стоят? Думаю, что проблема не в инклюде, а в самом файле.
 2. Покажите, что в файле.
 3. Какие операции, кроме отображения инклюдного файла, вы с ним делаете?

Comment: include ('/data/config.php');

if (!isset($_REQUEST['act'])) {
  $content = $config['index'];
}

 else if ($_REQUEST['act'] == "help") {
  $content = $config['help'];
}

 else if ($_REQUEST['act'] == "contacts") {
  $content = $config['contacts'];
}
echo<<<HTML
<div>$content</div>
HTML;

Comment: $ads_config = array (
'index' => "Главная страница",

'help' => "Страница поддержки",

'contacts' => "Контакти",


);

Comment: А то что в файле написанно `$config` а в include `$ads_config` ?

Comment: Да в конфиге небось массив с HTML данными

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего размер `data/config.php` достаточно большой, и основное время тратится на его генерацию, так как в нем содержатся все страницы сайта, то есть вы при выводе одной страницы генерируете код сразу для всех.

Из самого простого - поставить opcode кешер ([APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php), [XCache](http://xcache.lighttpd.net/)), но это поможет если содержимое страниц статично, в случае SQL-запросов и т.п. тогда нужно менять логику обработки.

Comment: ну собсно что я и написал ток другими словами.

Жесть, а что такое тоже сейчас делают?